# how can I resize a layer and have the other change to the proper ratio

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have monkey.psd that each layer is a part of a monkey and I want to resize monkey's head from 500x500 px to 300x300px and have other layer reduce the size to same ratio as before

Comment: Hi Niti Santikul, are the layers that also need to be scaled apart of the head itself? I would consider grouping all layers that need to be scaled and then doing a transform -> scale. I think a little clarification on how the layers are setup will help give a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you know you can multi-select layers (select several layers at once) in Photoshop, and then use the Transform command once for all the selected layers? If the layers are in different groups, be sure to expand the groups so that you can see that all the layers you want to resize are selected.

You have a specific number of pixels in mind, from 500×500 px to 300×300 px. That's the same as a Transform that scales the Height from 100% to 60% and the Width from 100% to 60%. As you modify the percentage, you'll see Photoshop updating the X and Y dimensions. See the illustration.

[image: Transform controls in a Windows version of Photoshop]

You could also resize the selected layers the other way: enter the X and Y dimensions, and then you'll see Photoshop update the Height and Width.

**A time-saving trick**. Before a transform action, I nudge the selection, 1 pixel left and then 1 pixel right, by using the keyboard nudge commands. This fits the selection exactly to the objects on the layers. This, in turn, ensures the dimensions in the Transform controls reflect only the objects, not the empty/transparent space around them.

Your version of Photoshop may differ.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank a lot ,but it mean I must calculate the different amount to percent every time I resize image such as 500 px to 300 or 500 to 400 right?

Comment: I've updated the answer to be more comprehensive. By the way, if this answer helps, it's good form to vote for it. Thanks.